SessionID lost when I refresh the page
I’ve developed an e-commerce website with Django REST Framework (DRF) as the backend and React as the frontend. Everything was functioning perfectly in my local environment. However, after deploying the application on Render, I’m encountering an issue with session authentication.
Specifically, the web browser is not saving the session ID in cookies after login or registration. I have already set
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN to include my domain name, but the problem persists.
is there any thing that I set wrong in my settings.py, I tried everything and it is still didn't works,  Is there something missing in my settings.py configuration?
settings.py
"""
Django settings for bookstore project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
import dj_database_url
from decouple import config

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "django-insecure-pi@oy&@v)656hz5#0on#^!yqrcy+1$dnjck4_6oc)&5r%uho-z"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["e-commerce-8io3.onrender.com", "localhost", "127.0.0.1"]

ALLOWED_HOSTS_DEPLOY = ["e-commerce-8io3.onrender.com"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "app",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "rest_framework",
    "corsheaders",
    "whitenoise",
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "bookstore.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "bookstore.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     "default": {
#         "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
#         "NAME": "bookstore",
#         "USER": "postgres",
#         "PASSWORD": "root",
#         "HOST": "localhost",
#         "PORT": "5432",
#     }
# }
DATABASE_URL = "postgres://bookstore_db2_user:RmjY6xsldUuJ7auyDnSdogbyUjAVX7Zl@dpg-cppvantds78s73efim3g-a.oregon-postgres.render.com/bookstore_db2"
DATABASES = {"default": dj_database_url.config(default=DATABASE_URL)}


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS_CLASSES": {
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",
    },
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    ),
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
MEDIA_URL = "/images/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "images")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://127.0.0.1",
    "http://0.0.0.0",
    "https://e-commerce-1-2ptc.onrender.com",
]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "https://e-commerce-1-2ptc.onrender.com",
]


CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "127.0.0.1:3000",
    "127.0.0.1::8000",  # Add the origin of your React app
    "https://e-commerce-1-2ptc.onrender.com",
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "e-commerce-1-2ptc.onrender.com"
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

this is login request from React
 const submitLogin =async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try{

      let response= await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/app/login/`, { username, password },{
        withCredentials:true,
        headers:{
          "X-CSRFToken":csrftoken
        }
      });
      console.log(response.data);
      navigate("/");

      
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
        // window.location.reload();


      };


How do you make the requests to the API: the JavaScript module also needs to store the cookies.
